Trying to rewrite a token in ANTLR4 in two different ways depending on siblings. How do I do that without rewriting the same token twice?

Target language JavaScript.
I have the pictured syntax tree. I want to rewrite
:d + 1 day
to
AddDay(:d, 1)
using an ANTLR4 listener. What's the best approach here?
And also, if my listener already implements
enterHostVariable where it replaces :d with ? , how can I prevent it from doing that when this occurrence of :d has already been rewritten to AddDay(:d, 1) and I don't want further changes?
